# Deleting dynamically created table rows using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table.

```html
<table id="table1">
 <tr id="table_row_1">
  <td>
   <button type="button" class="delete_button">Delete</button>
  </td>
  <td>
  <select id="project_list">
    <option>project1</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td>
  <select id="leave_list">
    <option>leave1</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td><input id="hours" >
  </td>
  <td><input id="notes">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

 <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
 <input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

I want to add and delete dynamic rows, my adding functionality works fine, and this is the code for that.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 var counter = 2;

 $("#addButton").click(function() {

  if (counter > 7) {
   alert("Only 7 rows allowed");
   return false;
  }

  var newTableRow = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id",'table_row_'+ counter);

  newTableRow.after().html(
   '<td><button type="button" id="delete_button">Delete</button></td>' + 
   '<td><select id="project_list"><option>project1</option></select></td>' +
   '<td><select id="leave_list"><option>leave1</option></select></td>' +
   '<td><input id="hours" ></td>' +
   '<td><input id="notes"></td>'
  );
       

 newTableRow.appendTo("#table1");

 counter++;
});
```

Now,when i press the delete button, I want to delete the particular row, can anyone help me with the jquery code for that.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: one question how are you assigning same id `delete_button` again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$( "#table1" ).on( "click", ".delete_button", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $( this ).parents( "tr" ).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

All you should need is this:

```
$('table').on('click', '.delete_button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thbis won't work, because the row is create dynamically and thus the click event won't fire on button entered in the dom later on.

Comment: Now our solutions are perfectly the same, except for the "return false" that I do not understand

Comment: I use `preventDefault` and `return false` to ensure the usual action of the element will not be called.

Comment: return false is needed only in "submit" event. In click event, e.preventDefault() is more than enought... Surely return false do not create any damage by the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

When adding new rows, you're adding "delete_button" as an id which will need to be changed to a class. The following code will then delete the row that the button is on

```
$('.delete_button').click(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```